# .cycle plugin dosn't work when ajaxed content in div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a portfolio website, with the Side navigation that when clicked stays on the same html page but loads new projects into the "content" div. I have so far got it to work but the problem is that each project page has multiple images of the same project, and the "next" and "Previous" links use the .cycle plugin, WHICH DOSE NOT WORK. please help. the website is located at www.yaasko.com and I have applied the ajax only to the two top thumbnails.

Thank in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the problem was livequery plugin. Its like live function but you can have functions inside it that are not based on .click event.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the new projects into the "content" div through AJAX, you'll need to use the jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event to bind functions to events for elements that get added after page load.

Comment: This is what I tried, but could not figure out how to code the live() thing into the cycle plugin? or where to place it.? sorry I'm new to ajax and jquery.

Comment: anything will help, tutorial that shows live() in practice with a function like cycle or similar. thank you so much!

Comment: I tried to do it this way, apply the live() on the index page that stays the same by adding this to the top of it. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js">
 $('#content #img a').live('click', function(){ 
  $('#img').cycle({
 fx:     'scrollUp', 
    speed:  1000, 
    timeout: 0,
    next:   '.next', 
    prev:   '.prev' 
 });
 } );
</script>

Comment: I just figured it out, not sure if I did it right cuz there is still some odd things, like when you click the next and previous buttons the image actually shrinks then you click it again then the .cycle plugin works? any ideas